# Why does minecraft run so slow?

Tags: performance, minecraft

I played minecraft on this computer until it was updated to 13.04, now I get 1-5 frames per second. These are my specs.

- Memory:3.9 GiB
- Processor:Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5500 @ 2.80GHz × 2
- Graphics(Before update said it was intel):Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.3, 128 bits)
- OS Type:32-bit
- Disk:485.9 GB

Answer (score 0):

> Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.3, 128 bits)

That is the root of all your issues. It means that it's using software to rendering your stuff. If your card doesn't support Hardware Acceleration there's nothing to do (most integrated Intel's doesn't), but buying a new card that supports it..